# Getting Stored Procedure Multiple result using linq to sql

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql

I have a Procedure which always returns 2 table.
How can i access to data in tables?
Here is a part of Procedure :

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[sp_Factor_Select](@FUID as varchar(31))
as
BEGIN

.
.
.

SELECT (Some Fields)
FROM tbl_Factors f 
INNER JOIN tbl_Customer c ON f.fld_CustomerID_FK = c.fld_CustomerID
INNER JOIN tbl_Stores s ON s.fld_SerialNumber = f.fld_SerialNumber

WHERE f.fld_FUID = @FUID


SELECT (Some Fields)
FROM tbl_WareInfo w
WHERE w.fld_FactorID_FK = @FactorID
END
```

In addition i use this following answer in this page : http://kishor-naik-dotnet.blogspot.com/2011/12/linq-multiple-result-set-of-procedure.html

Here is the part of code which i write it by help from upper link :

```
[FunctionAttribute(Name = "dbo.sp_Factor_Select")]
    [ResultType(typeof(tbl_Factor))]
    [ResultType(typeof(tbl_WareInfo))]
    public IMultipleResults GetMultipleResultSet([System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name = "FUID", DbType = "VarChar(31)")] string fUID)
    {
        try
        {
            IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), fUID);
            return (IMultipleResults)(result.ReturnValue);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

And here i call procedure :

```
ds_Result = db.GetMultipleResultSet(UID);
            var Factor = ds_Result.GetResult<tbl_Factor>().ToList<tbl_Factor>();
            var WareInfo = ds_Result.GetResult<tbl_WareInfo>().ToList<tbl_WareInfo>();
```

But because the table which procedure return in inner join between 3tables in sql i get in an error in this line :

```
 var Factor = ds_Result.GetResult<tbl_Factor>().ToList<tbl_Factor>();
```

my problem is what is the typeof the tables which procedure return ?
what typeof should i write here?

```
[ResultType(typeof(tbl_Factor))]
[ResultType(typeof(tbl_WareInfo))]
```

Comment: Just don't do it. Create 2 stored procedures

Comment: @teovankot the post edited whould you see it again? and i can't create 2 procedure.all of them should be in oneprocedure